# How to find items without relation to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I got a problem to exclude items on my MySQL query. I want to get all animals that have no relation to "Asia" e.g.

My tables look like that.

```
Table 'animals'
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Tiger        |
|  2 | Lion         |
|  3 | Spider       |
|  4 | Bird         |
+----+--------------+
```

Table 'continent'

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Europe       |
|  2 | Asia         |
|  3 | Africa       |
+----+--------------+
```

Table 'relations'

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | animal | continent |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |         1 |
|  2 |      2 |         1 |
|  3 |      2 |         2 |
|  4 |      2 |         3 |
|  5 |      3 |         3 |
|  6 |      4 |         2 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

This is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT    a.`id`,
          a.`name`
FROM      a.`animals` AS a
LEFT JOIN `relations` AS r
       ON r.`animal` = a.`id`
WHERE     r.`continent` != 2
ORDER BY  a.`name` asc;
```

The problem ist that this gives me the following result:

```
Lion
Spider
Tiger
```

The thing is that "Lion" has a relation to continent Asia (ID 2) and shouldn't be in the results. Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: you have lion id 2 in the relation table for continent 1

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to show only these animals for which there is no relation to Asia continent:

```
select a.*
from animals a
where not exists (
  select 1
  from relations r
  join continent c on
    c.id = r.continent
  where c.name = 'Asia'
    and a.id = r.animal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.name
FROM animals a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relations r INNER JOIN continent c
                      ON r.continent = c.id
                  WHERE a.id = r.animal AND c.name = 'Asia');
```

[image]

### Demo

The idea here is that for each animal, we scan the `relations` table joined to `continent` searching for the same animal being assigned to the Asia continent.  If we *can't* find that relationship, then retain that particular animal.

Comment: Won't this result in a performance issue as the table gets bigger and bigger?

Comment: Performance issue as compared to _which_ alternative?  Without comparing my solution to a different approach, your question makes no sense.  The answer I gave should be at least as performant as a join approach.  The other approach which comes to mind is aggregation, but in that case, if you look at what the DBMS will have to do to get an answer, it looks very similar to the answer I gave.

Comment: If you need performance, e.g. because your actual tables are very large and/or you have to run this query often, then you need some help with tuning.  That could be a second question after you close out this one.

Comment: What would you do to achieve a better performance? I thought this would be the right way to separate all data in a relational database.

Comment: Your table design is spot-on, nothing wrong there.  In terms of how to get a _fast_ answer, you have to look into things like adding indices to your tables, trying out different queries to see what runs the fastest, etc.  Again, great topic for a second question, out of scope for what you asked above.

Answer (score 0):

You obtain  liion because you have lion (id 2) in the relation table for continent ASIA

could be you need  the animal that are only i continent different for asia  then

```
    SELECT    a.`id`,
              a.`name`
    FROM      a.`animals` AS a
    LEFT JOIN `relations` AS r
           ON r.`animal` = a.`id`
    WHERE     r.`continent` != 2 
    AND a.id not in (
        select animal from relation where continent = 2
    )
    ORDER BY  a.`name` asc;
```

Comment: .. @KamilG.   . just a wrong typing anyway already upvoted  your answer  for thank the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It's because Lion have a relation with another country that isn't Asia.
What you want to do is :

```
SELECT a.id, a.name 
FROM animals a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT r.animal FROM relations r WHERE r.continent = 2
)
ORDER BY a.name DESC;
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* from animal A where a.id not in(select animal from relations where continent=2);
```

Comment: I think the OP would like to use the continent name `Asia` in the query, rather than an arbitrary id value.

Comment: Ok ,So we can write this as : select a.* from animal A where a.id not in(select animal
  from relations r join continent c on
    c.id = r.continent
  where c.name = 'Asia'
    and a.id = r.animal);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.